# Check if query was successful

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql-delete, delete-row

Lets say I have a **categories table** and then I have **products table**.

Each product belongs to some category.

Now, I want to remove a category which is assigned to some products.

This will cause an error, because I can not remove something from database because of database relations. My code below removes a row from a table (using jquery) but it removes the category for real only if it no product is using it.

I am trying to create some error warning when I click on `Delete` icon and the category can not be removed. How can I do that? I would prefer some jQuery popup window with the warning, but I don't really know how should I check for the error in the first place.

**EDIT:**
I have tried to use `echo 1;` and `echo 0;` as `response` for `ajax` but I am getting the warning message every time I want to remove something, even if there is no error.

```
<tbody>
   <?php
   $cat_list = "SELECT * FROM games_category";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $cat_list);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $id = $row['id'];
       $name = $row['name'];
       ?>
       <tr>
           <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
           <td>
               <span class='delete_game_cat' id='del_<?php echo $id; ?>'><img src="../images/remove.png" alt="" title="Delete" class="icon"/></span>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <?php
   }
   ?>
</tbody>
```

Here is script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Delete
   $('.delete_game_cat').click(function(){
       var el = this;
       var id = this.id;
       var splitid = id.split("_");

       // Delete id
       var deleteid = splitid[1];

       // AJAX Request
       $.ajax({
           url: 'delete_game_cat.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: { id:deleteid },
           success: function(response){
                if(response===1){
                   // Removing row from HTML Table
                   $(el).closest('tr').css('background','tomato');
                   $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(600, function(){
                       $(this).remove();
                   });
                }else{
                    alert("This category cannot be deleted!");
                }
           }
       });
   });
});
```

And sql query:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$query = "DELETE FROM games_category WHERE id =".$id;

if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
    echo 1;
}else{
    echo 0;
}
```

Comment: "This will cause an error,"  - please share more details. What does that mean? Also, be warned that your `DELETE` query is widely open for SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

```
$ver = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if(!$ver)
{
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    die();
}
else
{
    echo "Query succesfully executed!";
}
```

try this